# How to fill a ComboBox on the selection change from second ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

I have two comboBoxes, one is CountryCombo and second is StateCombo.

What I want is the that when i the clicks country combo and select a one country then the States of that the country should get populated in the State Combo.

I have tried things many many many but nothing working.  Below is my code of how my CountryCombo is getting filled.

```
query="select CountryName from CountryMaster"

if dr.hasRows()
{
  while dr.read()
  {
    countrycombo.items.add(dr(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please add more detail? Table Schema would be fine :)

Comment: i have 5 tables in my databases...and sir can u please tell more about the schema??what schema are you talking about????

Comment: Schema - the structure of your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below code,and please do some homework before posting a question.

```
    Private Sub countryCombo_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    Dim query As String
    query = "select StateName from StateMaster where CountryId='" & countryCombo.SelectedValue & "'"

    if dr.hasRows()
    {
         while dr.read()
          {
              Statecombo.items.add(dr(0))
          }
    }
    End Sub
```

This will populate your Statecombo on the selection change of countryCombo.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim cm1, cm2 As New DataColumn
    cm1.ColumnName = "CountryName"
    cm1.DataType = GetType(String)
    cm2.ColumnName = "CountryID"
    cm2.DataType = GetType(String) 'or integer
    dt.Columns.Add(cm1)
    dt.Columns.Add(cm2)
    'contry = here select your data

    Dim dr As DataRow
    dr = dt.NewRow
    dr(0) = "Select One"
    dr(1) = "-1"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    For Each item In contry
        dr = dt.NewRow
        dr(0) = item.CountryName
        dr(1) = item.CountryID
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next

    Drp.DataSource = dt
    Drp.DataTextField = "CountryName"
    Drp.DataValueField = "CountryID"
    Drp.DataBind()
```

with this code you can fill your dropdown. you can write sub like this and put it on selected change of this dropdown. Have good time!
add this part and make sure you have post back on dropdown list if its web form.

```
Protected Sub Drpcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Drpcountry.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim db as new linqdatacontext 
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim cm1, cm2 As New DataColumn
    cm1.ColumnName = "stateName"
    cm1.DataType = GetType(String)
    cm2.ColumnName = "stateID"
    cm2.DataType = GetType(String) 'or integer
    dt.Columns.Add(cm1)
    dt.Columns.Add(cm2)
    Dim stateslist = From i in db.tb_states where i.countryid = drpcountry.selectedvalue select i

    Dim dr As DataRow
    dr = dt.NewRow
    dr(0) = "Select One"
    dr(1) = "-1"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    For Each item In stateslist 
        dr = dt.NewRow
        dr(0) = item.stateName
        dr(1) = item.stateID
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next

    Drpstate.DataSource = dt
    Drpstate.DataTextField = "stateName"
    Drpstate.DataValueField = "stateID"
    Drpstate.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: if you want to use linq you can select your data like this: `country = From i in db.countrymaster select i.countryID, i.countryName`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the original poster's question: you have shown how to load the country combo, which is good information, but they would like to know how to fill a second combo with the list of states when a given country is selected in the first combo.

Answer (score 0):

the code you show is the (incomplete) code that fills your CountryCombo : Please share also the code that fills the StateCombo on new Country Selection, since it is that part that causes you problems.

Anyway you should avoid manipulating directly ComBoBox items, and instead you Should Bind both Combo To ObservableCollection, say to

```
 Public Property CountryCollection as New ObservableCollection(Of Country)
```

and

```
 Public Property StateCollection As New ObservableCollection(Of State).
```

And for both Country and State Object, overload ToString() sub to have Country/State name displayed
in the Combos.

Now fill the CountryCollection with your countries, and on a SelectionChanged of the CountryCombo, retrieve the list of state ( = state having CountryCombo.SelectedItem.CountryID as CountryID) then populate your StateCollection with this query result (Clear() then add()).

Test step by step : check that your country / state queries are returning good results with BreakPoints/ Debugger. If you bind to ObservableCollection, the queries should now be the only problem.